# Partitioning a file for parallel download

Tags: python, floating-point, numbers, int, division

I want to make a multi-threaded downloader (in Python) and I need to tell each thread where to start and how many bytes to download. For that I get the remote file size and divide it, for example, to 2. Now, let's say that the remote file size is 5: when I divide the number to 2, I get 2 as result. Now I can start the download but I will lose a byte (because `2*2=4`, not 5). I can't use float numbers because I can't download half of a byte. How I could divide that number and to get a list with `[2, 3]`, for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`divmod`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#divmod):

```
>>> divmod(5, 2)
(2, 1)
>>>
```

This tells you, that 5 divided by 2 is 2, remainder 1, so the last piece will be 2 + 1 = 3.

```
>>> divmod(12345, 6)
(2057, 3)
```

Here, you'll have 5 chunks at 2057 and a last slice at 2057+3.

This algorithm will also work for cases, where division is without remainder:

```
>>> divmod(12345, 5)
(2469, 0)
```

Here, you'll have 4 chunks at 2469 plus a last slice at 2469+0.

So, your chunk sizes could be computed as:

```
def chunk_sizes(filesize, num_chunks):
    d, r = divmod(filesize, num_chunks)
    result = [d] * num_chunks
    result[-1] += r
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the size of each chunk, you can simply add the remainder of the division to the last element:

```
>>> file_size = 11
>>> no_of_chunks = 3
>>> chunks = [file_size / no_of_chunks] * no_of_chunks
>>> chunks[-1] += file_size % no_of_chunks
>>> chunks
[3, 3, 5]
```

You can also modify that to distribute the remainder across all chunks, so that the size of the chunks deviates by at most 1:

```
>>> for i in range(file_size % no_of_chunks):
>>>    chunks[i] += 1
>>> chunks
[4, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Special case the last thread -- assign it to get however many bytes are left.